# Material UI - Date Time Picker safari browser issue

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, material-ui, mobile-safari

I have used Date Picker for my Application
it is working as expected in android chrome browser but safari is showing some UI issues. can anyone please solve this

```html
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
            <DateTimePicker
                renderInput={(props) => (
                    <CustomTextfield
                        {...props}
                        {...InputProps}
                        id={props.id}
                        name={props.name}
                        placeholder={props.placeholder}
                        error={props.error}
                        helperText={props.helperText}
                    />
                )}
                label={props.label}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                {...props}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
```

this is giving me in safari browser as [image]

Any solution for solving this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using "setTimeout" and "blur".

```
 onOpen={() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       const el = document.activeElement;
       if (el) {
          (el as HTMLElement).blur();
       }
    });
 }}
```

Comment: instead of onOpen() use onViewChange(), but then your solution works (MUI v5, Safari)